# idempotent bundle homomorphism has constant rank

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles

I am reading Introduction to differential topology, T.H Bröcker & K. Janich and I could not solve the following exercise:

Let $(E,\pi, X) $ be a vector bundle over a connected space $X$, let $f: E \rightarrow E$ be a vector bundle homomorphism and $f\circ f=f$. show that $f$ has constant rank.

I tried to find an open neighborhood $U$ s.t on this neighborhood $f$ has constant rank $k$. Then I would like to use connectedness of $X$ to extend this rank everywhere. But obviously this is not working since I have an counterexamples on the $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and also I haven't used the fact that $f\circ f=f$.

If you can help me I will appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "constant rant" in title is pretty funny

Comment: upps !! Thank you for your remark :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n$ be the rank of $E$, let $I\subset M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of idempotent matrices, and let $I_k\subset I$ be the set of idempotent matrices of rank $k$ for each $k$ such that $0\leq k\leq n$.  By looking at what $f$ looks like in local trivializations of $E$, you can see that it suffices to prove that for each $k$, $I_k$ is clopen as a subset of $I$.

How do you prove that $I_k$ is clopen in $I$?  There are several ways you could do this, but the following is probably the easiest.  Every rank $k$ idempotent matrix has characteristic polynomial $x^{n-k}(x-1)^k$.  The map sending a matrix to the coefficients of its characteristic polynomial is a continuous map $M_n(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}^n$.  It follows that each $I_k$ is closed in $I$, and thus also open, since $I\setminus I_k=\bigcup_{j\neq k} I_j$ is a finite union of closed sets and hence also closed.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your answer. But I still have some points to ask: As far as I could see, you are defining a map $\phi$from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ given by $\phi(x,f_{x})$ equals to the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial. However continuity of this map is not clear for me since the map is not from $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Even if I write this function using local trivializations then $f$ will looks like $f(x,v)=(x,A_{x}v)$ where $A_{x}\in I_{k}$

Comment: In a local trivialization, you can identify $f$ with the function $x\mapsto A_x$, which is a map $X\to M_n(\mathbb{R})$ (which actually lands in $I\subset M_n(\mathbb{R})$).  Composing it with the "coefficients of the characteristic polynomial" map gives you a map $X\to \mathbb{R}^n$.  Note that a priori this map is only locally defined (on an open subset of $X$ where you have chosen a local trivialization), but it is actually globally defined because a different choice of local trivialization will conjugate $A_x$ by some invertible matrix, which does not change the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Why does the map $X \to M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $ x \mapsto A_x $ needs to be continuous? I think we need to use continuity of this map to then use the fact that $X$ is connected.

Comment: @user392559: That is trivial: identifying $E$ with $X\times\mathbb{R}^n$, then the $i$th column of $A_x$ is just the second coordinate of $f(x,e_i)$ where $e_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector.

Comment: @EricWofsey I have a few observations/questions. So, your proof works even when $f\circ f=\lambda f$ for some fixed scalar $\lambda$. Thus, if $g$ is a bundle endomorphism with $g\circ g=\text{Id}$, then $(g-\text{Id})^2=-2(g-\text{Id})$, and hence $\ker (g-\text{Id})$ is a subbundle, which answers the question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3364968/591889. Am I right?

Comment: @Random: That would work.  You can also observe more directly that if $g\circ g=Id$ then there are only finitely many possibilities for the characteristic polynomial of $g$ (all the eigenvalues must be $\pm 1$) so by the same argument the characteristic polynomial is locally constant, and thus so is the dimension of the fixed subspace.

Comment: Why is that a different local trivialization will only conjugate $A_x$?
And why is that this extends it to the whole space? As far as I understand by taking a different local trivialization, if this is over another open set that doesn't overlap with your first local trivialization then you can't really conclude that the matrix is just a conjugation of the matrix on the other trivialization, and if it does overlap then you can only conclude this in the intersection of the open sets in which the trivializations overlap.

Comment: @H4z3: It only makes sense to talk about $A_x$ in a local trivialization if the point $x$ is in that local trivialization.  So I'm only talking about comparing the $A_x$'s you get from different local trivializations that actually contain the point $x$.

Comment: Yes I get that, but then when thinking f as the function $f(x) = A_x$ the fact that $I_k$ is clopen only says that $f$ has constant rank on a connected neighborhood $U$ because how you're using local trivializations. You're not really using the fact that the space $X$ is connected

Comment: I think you could use the fact that because $f$ is a bundle homomorphism $f|_{E_x}$ is a linear map and has a matrix representation $A_x$ so instead of using the local representation by using trivializations just take the map that sends $x$ to $A_x$ and this will be a continuous map defined on the whole space

Comment: @H4z3: If you take the matrix representation in an arbitrary way at each point, why would the map sending $x$ to $A_x$ be continuous?  That's the whole point of using the local trivialization: it's what guarantees that $A_x$ is a continuous function of $x$, using the continuity of $f$.

Comment: Yeah but by using that representation you're only proving that f has constant rank on a trivialization

Comment: Also you can prove the continuity of such function from the continuity of $f$, I believe that this is another exercise by brocker in the same chapter