# The set of fixed points of a bundle homomorphism that is an involution, is a subbundle.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

Let $(E,\pi , X)$ be a n-dimensional vector bundle over a connected space $X$ and $f:E \to E$ a bundle homomorphism with $f\circ f = Id_{E}$. Show that $ Fix(f):= \{ v\in E | f(v)=v \}$ is a subbundle of $E$.

This is problem 3 from chapter 3 of Bröcker's book Introduction to Differential Topolpgy.
The idea I had involved using the rank theorem:
For $x\in X$, let $E_x := \pi ^{-1} ({x}) $. By definition of bundle homomorphism, we have that $f_x : E_x \to E_x $ is linear, and since $f$ is an involution, in particular, $f_x$ is invertible, so its rank is $n$, and thus, $f$ has constant rank.
Then, by the rank theorem, there exist chart bundles of $E$, $(\phi, U), (\psi , U) $, such that $\psi \circ f \circ  \phi ^{-1} : U \times \mathbb{R} ^n \to U \times \mathbb{R} ^n $, $\psi \circ f \circ  \phi ^{-1} (u, (v_1,..., v_n)) = (u,(v_1,...,v_n))$, and thus:
$\psi \circ f \circ  \phi ^{-1} (U\times \mathbb{R} ^n ) = U\times \mathbb{R} ^n$.

Since $f \circ  \phi ^{-1} (U\times \mathbb{R} ^n ) =f (\pi ^{-1} (U))$, it would be enough to show that $f (\pi ^{-1} (U))= \pi ^{-1} (U) \cap Fix(f)$.

It is clear to me that $\pi ^{-1} (U) \cap Fix(f) \subseteq f (\pi ^{-1} (U))$, but the other set containment is not clear to me and I don't even know if it is true. Also, I haven't used the fact that the base space $X$ is connected.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your application of the rank theorem makes $f$ look like the identity, which is obviously not right.  You're ignoring the vector space structure and linear mapping when you work just with the smooth structure.  You need to study the $1$-eigenspaces of $f_x$ as $x$ varies. Why do they vary smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

You can write $Fix(f) = \ker(f - Id_{E})$. A kernel of a bundle map $f - Id_{E}$ is known to be a subbundle of $E$, if and only if it has a constant rank.

For each $x \in X$, write $r_{\pm}(x) := rank( f_{x} \mp Id_{E_{x}})$. You have to show that $r_{+}(x)$ is constant in $x$. Since $f_{x}^{2} = Id_{E_{x}}$, it follows that $E_{x} = \ker(f_{x} - Id_{E_{x}}) \oplus \ker(f_{x} + Id_{E_{x}})$. Consequently, one has $r_{+}(x) + r_{-}(x) = rank(E)$.

Finally, $r_{\pm}(x)$ both have the following property: for each $x_{0} \in X$, there is its open neighborhood $U$, such that $r_{\pm}(x) \geq r_{\pm}(x_{0})$ for all $x \in U$. This follows from the fact that $r_{\pm}(x)$ can be expressed as a rank of some square matrix depending smoothly on a $x$, which has this property.

But since $r_{+}(x) + r_{-}(x)$ is constant for all $x \in U$, we must have $r_{\pm}(x) = r_{\pm}(x_{0})$ for all $x \in U$. Since $X$ is connected (thus also path connected, if $X$ is a manifold), then $r_{\pm}(x)$ must be constant on entire $X$.